# How to set values in a FormArray in angular?

Tags: angular, formarray

I am trying to enter values in a FormGroup that has a FormArray inside but I have problem with this array as the data is not mapped
My form

```
this.jobOpportunity = this.fb.group({
  title: ['', Validators.required],
  description: ['', Validators.required],
  requirements: this.fb.array([]),
  initDate: ['', [Validators.required, this.dateValidator]],
  endDate: ['', [Validators.required, this.dateValidator]],
  address: ['', Validators.required],
  companyId: ['', Validators.required],
  departmentId: ['', Validators.required],
  isActive: [false],
});

requirements(): FormArray {
  return this.jobOpportunity.get("requirements") as FormArray
}

newRequirement(): FormGroup {
  return this.fb.group({
     title: ''
 })
}
```

Where I try to enter the values that my Api returns:

```
this.api.getByIdJobOpportunity(this.jopId.id).subscribe(
    (data: any) => {
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['title'].setValue(data.title);
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['description'].setValue(data.description);
      const dateInitSplit = data.initDate.split('T');

      //I try to map my data to the FormArray here

      this.jobOpportunity.controls['requirements'].patchValue(data.requirements);

      //I tried with setValue but this returns an error and pachValue does not enter 
      //my data

      this.jobOpportunity.controls['initDate'].setValue(dateInitSplit[0]);
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['address'].setValue(data.address);
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['companyId'].setValue(data.companyId);
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['departmentId'].setValue(data.departmentId);
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['isActive'].setValue(data.isActive);
      const dateEndSplit = data.endDate.split('T');
      this.jobOpportunity.controls['endDate'].setValue(dateEndSplit[0]);
      this.url = data.image;
      this.formTitle = 'Actualizar empleo';
      this.labelBtn = 'Actualizar';
    },
 );
```

Reference image

[image]

When he tried with setValue() he returned this error

[image]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Error Reason:**

You are trying to patch/set values on an empty `FormArray` with no formgroups.

`requirements: this.fb.array([]),` created a control `requirements` that will be a `FormArray` but currently empty. So, when you get the response from your API, you try to patch/set a value on that empty Form Array. It needs to create a `FormGroup` for each item coming from API.

**Solution:**

Assuming that your API returns the array of objects of `requirements`. Iterate over the requirements array and create a new form group + patch value in it.

```
this.api.getByIdJobOpportunity(this.jopId.id).subscribe(
  (data: any) => {

....

if(Array.isArray(data.requirements)){
  data.requirements.forEach(item=>{
   let newControl=newRequirement(); //Creates a new formgroup
   newControl.patchValue(item); //Patch value 
   this.requirements().push(newControl); //Add the control to the FormArray
})
}

...
}
```